# PictureBox style Message boxes

Tags: c#, image, picturebox, messagebox

I was just wondering if there was a way for someone to bring up an image like you bring up a message box, in it's own little window.

Comment: I don't think you can. But coding your own MessageBox is really not a big deal.

Comment: make new form, no border (put button for closing form, or using keypress) and dock image into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a new form with a PictureBox that fill the form. Set the FormBorderdStyle form's property to FixedToolWindow.